# Angularjs ng-checked behaviour not consistent

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-ng-checked

I am using angularjs, and theres a edit view for one form, where I am trying to bind the previously used values. Below is my code/HTML. I am also using typescript for this and controller as format.

**HTML:**

```
<label ng-repeat="type in Ctrl.Types">
    <input type="radio" name="Type" ng-model="Ctrl.Foo.Type" ng-value="type.TypeId" required ng-checked="type.TypeName===Ctrl.Foo.TypeName" />
    {{ type.TypeName }} {{ type.TypeName===Ctrl.Foo.TypeName }}
</label>
```

**Typescript JS For getting Foo**

```
Foo:any;
getFoo = (Fooid) => {
    this.FooResource.getFooById(Fooid).then((response) => {
        this.Foo= response.data;
    });
};
```

I am getting all the values, everything is binding, except the radio buttons, I can see checked="checked" in html inspect element, I have also outputted expression along in html, which is also as expected, but i can not see radio selected(dot in radio) many times, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt. Types load at different times and Foo at different time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by Adding a function in ng-checked instead of an expression and in that function, I returned true or false, and also set the ng-model to that selected value before returning, which was missing before as below.

```
<label ng-repeat="type in Ctrl.Types">
    <input type="radio" name="Type" ng-model="Ctrl.Foo.Type" ng-value="type.TypeId" required ng-checked="Ctrl.isTypeChecked(type)" />
    {{ type.TypeName }}
</label>
```

JS:

```
isTypeChecked = (t) => {   
    if (t.TypeName === this.Foo.TypeName) {
        this.Foo.Type = t.TypeId;
    }    
    return t.TypeName === this.Foo.TypeName;
};
```

getFoo is unchanged from before.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind multiple values to the radio button. ngModel and ngValue will bind the data to the radio button and in your example you are trying to bind 2 different values to the radio button. Hence, you will see inconsistent behaviour.

Try this.

```
<label ng-repeat="type in Ctrl.Types">
    <input type="radio" name="Type" ng-model="type.TypeId" required ng-checked="type.TypeName===Ctrl.Foo.TypeName" />
    {{ type.TypeName }} {{ type.TypeName===Ctrl.Foo.TypeName }}
</label>
```

or

```
<label ng-repeat="type in Ctrl.Types">
    <input type="radio" name="Type" ng-value="type.TypeId" required ng-checked="type.TypeName===Ctrl.Foo.TypeName" />
    {{ type.TypeName }} {{ type.TypeName===Ctrl.Foo.TypeName }}
</label>
```

[Here's the doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue)

----EDIT----

Try this...Remove ngChecked

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <label>Enter a character</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="Ctrl.Foo.TypeName">
    <div ng-repeat="type in Ctrl.types">
        <input type="radio" name="Type" ng-model="Ctrl.Foo.TypeName" ng-value="type.TypeName" required />{{type.TypeName}}
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/hv5r5n9p/4/)

Comment: I can not use ng-model='type.TypeId', its the available option list , i want to bind the selected value to Foo., hence ng model